# Codeigniter query is not returning all records from the left table. Only returns the matching records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Query returns only the matching records in the joined tables. What am I doing wrong? I am trying to display all the records from the agents table whether there are matching records in loans table or not. Maybe my logic for what I am trying to achieve is wrong.

```
    $select = "agents.person_id, CONCAT(people.first_name, ' ', people.last_name) as last_name, SUM(loans.referral_amount) as referral_amount, COUNT( DISTINCT loans.customer_id ) as no_customers";
            $this->db->select($select, false);
            $this->db->from('agents');
            $this->db->join('people', 'agents.person_id=people.person_id', 'LEFT');
            $this->db->join('loans', 'agents.person_id=loans.referral_agent_id AND loans.loan_status = "paid" AND loans.delete_flag = 0', 'LEFT');
            $this->db->where('agents.deleted', 0);
    return $this->db->get();



Table: agents

+-----------+---------+--+
| person_id | deleted |  |
+-----------+---------+--+
|         1 |       0 |  |
|         2 |       0 |  |
|         3 |       1 |  |
|         4 |       0 |  |
+-----------+---------+--+

Table: loans

|   | loan_status | referral_amount | referral_agent_id | delete_flag|customer_id |
|---|-------------|-----------------|-------------------|-------------|-------------|
|   | paid        | 10              | 1                 | 0           | 2           |
|   | pending     | 20              | 1                 | 0           | 2           |
|   | approved    | 30              | 3                 | 1           | 1           |


Table: people

| person_id | first_name | last_name |
|-----------|------------|-----------|
| 1         | Test       | Ken       |
| 2         | Lorem      | Ipsum     |
| 3         | Stack      | Over      |

The result I am getting

| name     | referral amount | no of customers |
|----------|-----------------|-----------------|
| Test Ken | 10              | 1               |

What I am expecting

| name        | referral amount | no of customers |
|-------------|-----------------|-----------------|
| Test Ken    | 10              | 1               |
| Lorem Ipsum | null            | null            |
| Stack Over  | null            | null            |
```

Comment: Please share the schema, then the output you're getting with your code, and then the expected output.

Comment: Table: c19_agents
person_id (int)
deleted (int)                                                                                                                                                         Table: c19_people
person_id (int)
first_name (int)  last_name(int)
                                                                                                                     Database: Table: c19_loans
loan_id int(11) 
customer_id int(11)
referral_amount int(10)
loan_status enum('pending',
'approved', 'on
going', 'paid')
referral_agent_id int(10) 
delete_flag int(11)

Comment: Add it in the post, it's difficult to read in comments.

Comment: Sorry if the schema is not clear. This is my first post here. My expected result is to display all records from c19_agents table and matching records from joined table. The result I am getting is just one record from the c19_agents table with matching columns.

Comment: No problem, just add everything in the post instead of writing it in comments. And by expected result I meant show a few rows with sample data in every table and then show the expected result that should come. This way it makes it clear for the reader to understand what is needed even if the statement is not clear.

Comment: Okay let me edit again with sample data

Comment: @Aashishgaba done adding result and schema

Comment: Never add links, when you can simply create a table here with a few examples as text in the post. And the link that you shared contains so much data. It's not easy for anyone to go through it. When someone says to add the schema, what you need to do is, list the table name and all of its column in a clear format. And when it comes to your output and expected output, you should create simple data in a table in the post, and then show the output of what your code does using that data(in your case), and what is actually expected. I'm telling you this for future posts.

Comment: I've added a solution. Please take a look and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: how does the working regular SQL query look like?

Comment: @Vickel Sorry I realised the regular SQL is behaving same way as the CI queries which makes me think something is wrong with my logic. Initially I had selected everything (*). I have updated the question to be clear so please have a look.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Noted. I'll change that. Doesn't affect the records though, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

```
$select = "c19_agents.person_id, referral_sum.user_referral_amount, CONCAT(c19_people.first_name, ' ', c19_people.last_name) as agents_name, customer_count.no_customers, referral_sum.user_referral_amount, phone_number";
        $this->db->select($select, false);
        $this->db->from('agents');
        $this->db->join('people', 'agents.person_id=people.person_id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('(SELECT c19_loans.referral_agent_id, SUM(c19_loans.referral_amount)
                   as user_referral_amount
                   FROM c19_loans
                       WHERE c19_loans.delete_flag = 0 AND c19_loans.loan_status = "paid"
                       GROUP BY c19_loans.referral_agent_id) referral_sum', 'c19_agents.person_id = referral_sum.referral_agent_id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('(SELECT c19_loans.referral_agent_id, COUNT( DISTINCT c19_loans.customer_id)
                    as no_customers
                    FROM c19_loans
                        WHERE c19_loans.delete_flag = 0 AND customer_id > 0
                        GROUP by c19_loans.referral_agent_id) customer_count', 'c19_agents.person_id = customer_count.referral_agent_id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->where('agents.deleted', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as far I can see you're mixing "Standard Query" with the "Query Builder", is good practice to use only one (preferably the Query Builder in case you switch to another database engine).

Also in the second Join you're making a "AND" comparison, although [this is valid](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html), you could try to make the *joins* work first. I think is working now but to be sure please, debug your query print the result and fix it according to [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html),

```
$select = "agents.person_id, CONCAT(people.first_name, ' ', people.last_name) as last_name, SUM(loans.referral_amount) as referral_amount, COUNT( DISTINCT loans.customer_id ) as no_customers, people.phone_number";

$this->db->select($select, false);
$this->db->from('agents');
$this->db->join('people', 'agents.person_id=people.person_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('loans', 'agents.person_id=loans.referral_agent_id', 'LEFT'); 
$this->db->where('loans.loan_status', 'paid');
$this->db->where('loans.delete_flag', 0);
$this->db->where('agents.deleted', 0);
$this->db->get();

print_r($this->db->last_query());
```

(Final recommendation: please always use notation `database.column` in your queries whenever you're using a Join, is easier to understand and avoid errors in case two databases have a column with the same name)

Comment: Appreciate your response. Still the same result. I record. One whose loan_status is set to paid.

Comment: @Elber CM: You write: *Also in the second Join you're making a "AND" comparison, this isn't valid.* **That's wrong**, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: I'm really stuck with this one. I think the multiple where clauses are filtering the final result thus giving me one record.

Comment: @Vickel Thanks for the correction. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @AmbroseKyusya Try to debug the query without the $this->db->where conditions. To see if at least you are getting the correct columns, then add a condition one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$select = "agents.person_id, CONCAT(people.first_name, ' ', people.last_name) as last_name, SUM(loans.referral_amount) as referral_amount, COUNT( DISTINCT loans.customer_id ) as no_customers, people.phone_number";

$this->db->select($select, false);
$this->db->from('agents');
$this->db->join('people', 'agents.person_id = people.person_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('loans', 'agents.person_id = loans.referral_agent_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->where('loans.loan_status', "paid");
$this->db->where('loans.delete_flag', 0);
$this->db->where('agents.deleted', 0);

$result = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Still 1 record. One whose loan_status is set to paid.

Comment: Did you check that there are other entries that satisfy this criteria but are not listed here. If so, please paste that example here.

Comment: I checked all the entries from the loan table and there is only one entry with status as paid, the one with loan_id as 71 customer id as 28, agent id as 20. The agent has first_name as Test and last_name as Agent. So the query is correct, as there's only one loan with paid status

Comment: That is right. That is not what I want to achieve though. I am trying to display all the records from the agents table whether there are matching records in loans table or not. Maybe my logic for what I am trying to achieve is wrong. Could you possibly suggest the right way to grab all records from agents table whether they match other tables or not?

Comment: I wrote the solution on the basis of the query you wrote in your post, and there's no statement in the question. I'd suggest you edit the post, stating your question clearly with a proper schema and example. Otherwise, it's difficult to help because now you're saying that you need something else. So please edit the question and the add relevant details. And read this before editing the question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: i have updated the question. The schema remains the same since its exactly what I have on my db.

Comment: Did you go through the link that i mentioned in the comment?

Comment: This is what I understand from your question. List all the agents with the data from the people table as well. So you want all the agents from the agents table. And the columns to be displayed should be
`$select = "agents.person_id, CONCAT(people.first_name, ' ', people.last_name) as last_name,  people.phone_number` . Is this what you mean?

Comment: I have updated the question. Yes, that is what I want plus referral_amount and customer_id that come from the loans table. Check the updated questions for more details. By the way thank you for your advice on how to post questions properly.

Comment: Hello @Aashish did you get time to look at the updated question, I'm really counting on your help.